# How use Dokku with django?

Tags: django, docker, dokku

I try use **dokku** for my web projects - deployment become cool. But I can't find information about two things.

1. Can I autocreate database from **dokku-util**? How?
2. How and where store media files without using **AWS**? I want use only my vps'.

P.S. Or may be you see good materials about full workflow for **dokku**?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add plugins to dokku.  Connect to your VPS, go to the /var/lib/dokku/plugins folder and then you can 'git clone' various plugins from github.  There are a list of plugins on the dokku site that will create mysql, postgresql, redis, and other databases.

While the plugins work great, I prefer to run a second VPS that just hosts databases.

1. There isn't really a good way of serving static files directly from django--even when it's under docker.  There is an app called dj-static that will help, but the author appears to be slow to update it for newer django releases.  (https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-static)